# SharePoint 2010 REST Webservice NOT substringof

Tags: web-services, rest, sharepoint-2010

I need to filter a SharePoint list with a REST webservice with a NOT contains operation.
There is a text field called "Inactive" containing a string. I would like to filter the list to show all items in which the field "Inactive" does NOT contain a certain string.
I already tried several way to do this, but none of them was successfull.

- `$filter=not substringof('R01', Inactive)`
- `$filter=(not%20substringof('R01', Inactive))`
- `$filter=substringof('R01', Inactive) ne true`

The positive query `$filter=substringof('R01', Inactive)` works fine.

I already searched for hours but couldn't find a solution.

Has someone solved this issue and could help me?
Best regards,
Remo

Answer (score 0):

I just found out while trying some more possibilities that $filter=(not substringof('R01',Inactive)) works on SP 2013 and also on SP2010.

It seems that I somehow made some typing errors before.

Comment: One importand informationt to add: If there are any empty entries for this field then the server will answer with an error.